# Problem with ashx and ajax file on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ashx

I have problem with `.ashx` files called from a JavaScript function ( standard Ajax ). Locally ( on my computer ) with *Visuall Studio* everything works perfect, but on my IIS 8 server ( Win 10 ), the `.ashx` files are not responding.

No error messages, just the Ajax'es return nothing ( not success ).
I have no idea why.

**EDIT:**
Now, I have an idea why: 
I found the reason, but it changed the problem.
**The reason is:**
it is impossible to load `Mysql.web`.
I checked, and those file where should be(?)

Has anyone any suggestions?

Comment: What is the response code returned for ashx ajax call?

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify, [edit] your question instead. Comments may or may not be shown initially. They do appear in order of votes. You also cannot format code properly in comments. Make it easy to help you by putting everything in one place --- the question. Can you provide your code as a [mcve] so that others can reproduce the problem?